# How to start and end an animation assigned keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

sorry if this has been asked already, but how do you make an animation start and end at first and last assigned keyframes rather than specify a frame number for the start and end frames separately?

While working on my character animations, I always end up changing the scale, adding extra elements, etc. of my animations and it's always a bother to go back to the timeline window and set the start and end conditions to what I want. Is there a more convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "preview range". You can call it via <kbd>P</kbd>:

[image: demo gif]

It will set a temporary play range, which you can toggle with this little clock icon near the start/end frames:

[image: demo pic]